# How can I get the title of the current tab in Terminal using applescript?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

In the example below there are three tabs. Their titles are bash, less, and ssh.

How can I use applescript get the title of the currently selected tab? In this case I hope it would return `less`.

[Picture.png http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/903/pictureqn.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/903/pictureqn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X 10.7 try something like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell first window of application "Terminal" to get custom title of selected tab'
```

Comment: Not sure about other versions, but in OS X v10.7.3, Terminal doesn't appear to set the custom title property for tabs. When I run this script I just get "Terminal" for every tab no matter what the application is actually showing.

Comment: You need to set the custom title. There are various ways to do that: http://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory

Comment: In OSX 10.7.3, no matter what you set the tab title to with the inspector, "custom title" remains "Terminal".